# Is it permissible to connect water softener drain(s) to tub/shower unit overflow drain? How?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drainage, water-softener

[image]My A.O. Smith water softener system (6-month sediment pre-filter, 6-year whole-house filter tank, 6-year descaler tank, and 6-month sediment post-filter) seems not up to the job of softening the local water. I got this system to avoid running electrical and putting a drain in the corner of the downstairs bath where water supply enters the house.

The system did not make it six months - much less six years (it seems seriously over-hyped). Since I now need to do what I should have done the first time (salt system with electric and drain), I am looking for easiest way to drain it (I have figured the electric out). The installation area (same place salt-less system is, where the water enters house) is in an alcove in that bathroom. The bathroom inexplicably (to me) does not have a floor drain.

If looking at the foundation wall (basement is fully complete as far as drywall, etc.) from entrance point into bathroom, tub/shower unit is on viewers left side of foundation wall with plumbing (drain, handles, etc.) on right ride of unit. Plumbing is inside a stub wall. The "U" shaped alcove with the water current softener in it is just the other side of the stub wall. Stub wall is about 30 inches deep and 30 inches wide - right side is the bathroom wall. To help hide the system, the alcove seems sized to be a good place for a door?

The house - built in 2014 - did not have a water shutoff at the entry point (in that bathroom) for some reason (am told it should have). It does have a shut-off now (installed as part of installing the saltless water softener system six months ago). The utility room that is 30 feet and several rooms away has a drain - but is not the water entry point.

Anyway, it seems to me (but am guessing it may be more complicated than I believe) that the closest drain (literally inches away from where the saltwater softener will be installed) is inside that stub wall for the tub/shower unit.

So, can I connect the (two) water softener drains to the of the tub/shower unit overflow drain inside the stub wall, and if so, how difficult would it be?

Comment: Your two questions (can I and how difficult) are both quite subjective. (Sure, and who knows?) You should revise to ask something more specific about the project. Also, it's very likely to be a code violation. Tub overflows are not designed, vented, or sized for additional loads, and you'll probably see blowback in your tub, along with noise.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it needs to be a permanent installation.

When draining the filers use a hose to the tub/shower drain.

Do not use/block the overflow, since it has an emergency function preventing the tub/shower overflow.

Permanent installation might have problem with code, while using hose does not.